# Grub boot error on cloned virtual machine

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, clone

While using virt-manager and connected to a Qemu/KVM Hypervisor, I cloned a virtual machine of an Ubuntu server installation, version 16.0.4 if it matters. When I try to boot the cloned virtual machine, I get the message:

```
Booting from Hard Disk... error: File '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod'
not found. Entering rescue mode... 
grub rescue>
```

The original virtual machine boots fine but the clone does not. 
Aside from a different MAC address on the network card, the clone should be an exact duplicate.

What is causing this error?

More importantly, how can I prevent it from happening, or fix the clone when it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to reinstall Grub, I can't tell you why it needs to be reinstalled myself but this is what you will need to enter (`/dev/sda1` is assumed to be the OS partition on disk `/dev/sda`, change as needed).

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
```